# What's the fastest way to return that indices of values of two arrays that are equal to each other?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have these two numpy arrays:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[8,7,3])
B = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[8,7,3])
```

It should return

```
[0,2]
```

Since the values at the 0th and 2nd index are equal to each other.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

I tried something like:

```
[val for val in range(len(A)) if A[val]==B[val]]
```

but got the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You are asking for the fastest way, but you seem to have trouble with getting it done in any way. I recommend to rephrase and clarify whether you need help in doing it at all or with optimising a working solution you have. This is important, because as it is your question might be interpreted as a camouflaged attempt to get any solution (often with the reason to get a homework done without admitting it; in that case please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions , which allows to ask openly about homework).

Answer (score 1):

You better look for vectorized solution so...

You can try do:

```
>>>np.where(np.all(A == B, axis=1))
array([0 2])
```

You can see the benefit of vectorization When it comes to speed here : https://chelseatroy.com/2018/11/07/code-mechanic-numpy-vectorization/amp/

Comment: Note that this solution only works if both arrays `A` and `B` are of the same shape. It additionally does not cover the case in which a match occurs multiple times, e.g., if `B=np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1], [1,2,3]])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
>>> [a in B for a in A]
[True, False, True]

>>> A[[a in B for a in A]]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [8, 7, 3]])

>>> np.where((A==B).all(axis=1))
(array([0, 2]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A.shape == B.shape` (otherwise just take `A=A[:len(B)]` and `B=B[:len(A)]`) consider:

```py
>>> A==B
[[ True  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]]

>>> (A==B).all(axis=1)
[ True False  True]

>>> np.argwhere((A==B).all(axis=1))
[[0]
 [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works also for arrays that do not match in their first dimension, i.e., have a different number of rows. It also works if a match occurs multiple times.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance


A = np.array([[1, 2 ,3], 
              [4, 5 ,6],
              [8, 7, 3]])

B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [3, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [9, 9, 9]])

res = np.nonzero(distance.cdist(A, B) == 0)
# ==> (array([0, 0]), array([0, 2]))
```

The result `res` is a tuple of two array, which represent the match index of the first and the second input array, respectively. So, in this example, the row at the 0th index of the first array matches the row of the 0th index of second array, and the row at the 0th index of the first array matches the row at the second index of the second array.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [174]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[8,7,3]])
     ...: B = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[8,7,3]])
```

Your list comprehension works fine for lists:

```
In [175]: Al = A.tolist(); Bl = B.tolist()
In [177]: [val for val in range(len(Al)) if Al[val]==Bl[val]]
Out[177]: [0, 2]
```

For lists `==` is a simple boolean test - same or not; for arrays it returns a boolean array, which can't be use in an if:

```
In [178]: Al[0]==Bl[0]
Out[178]: True
In [179]: A[0]==B[0]
Out[179]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

With arrays, you need to add a `all` as suggested by the error:

```
In [180]: [val for val in range(len(A)) if np.all(A[val]==B[val])]
Out[180]: [0, 2]
```

The list version will be faster.

But you can also compare the whole arrays, and take row by row `all`:

```
In [181]: A==B
Out[181]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [182]: np.all(A==B, axis=1)
Out[182]: array([ True, False,  True])
In [183]: np.nonzero(np.all(A==B, axis=1))
Out[183]: (array([0, 2]),)
```